# Not able to hold string from one form to other

Tags: c#, database, gridview

Able to show the database when c.Show() execute. When i close form 2 and click on the button6 the gridview on form 2 was empty. Any idea how to fix this bug?

Form 1:

```
private void System_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
                    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {

                        Bitmap picture = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                        ZoneStatus c = new ZoneStatus();
                        c.dbname = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.SafeFileName);
                        //c.Show();
                    }
    }

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ZoneStatus zoneStatus_form = new ZoneStatus();
        zoneStatus_form.Show();
    }
```

Form 2:

```
public string dbconnection;        
public string dbname {get;set;}

private void ZoneStatus_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbconnection = @"Data Source=" + dbname + ".db;Version=3;";
        SQLiteConnection sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(dbconnection);
        {
            sqliteCon.Open();
            // Create new DataAdapter
            using (SQLiteDataAdapter a = new SQLiteDataAdapter(
                "SELECT * FROM Alarm_Info", sqliteCon))
            {
                // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                a.Fill(dt);

                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; // to update my database
            }
            sqliteCon.Close();                
        }

    }
```

Comment: when you close form2, the values of dbconnection and dbname are lost.  this is how it is supposed to work.  Maybe you just want to hide the form.

Comment: @Plutonix  Hi, plutonix. So its that any way that i can hold the dbname and dbconnection?

Comment: If it is critical that Form2 have that information either pass it in the ctor or provide a way for the form to get it itself in formload, or pass the info in a method or as properties

Comment: @Plutonix Its that possible you can provide one simple example? Cause i still new to C# . Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

change "public string dbname" to "public static string dbname".(same with dbconnection if you want to use that variable too.)
let's assume that you have declare your string in from1 and you want to use this string in form2 so your code will look like this.

form1:

```
public static string dbname;
```

in form2 create object of form1 and access this variable like this.

form2:

```
form1 objf1 = new form1();
string str=objf1.dbname;
```

now you can do whatever you want to do with variable dbname. you can assign to other variable like i did.

Comment: hi, it was not able to call dbname from form1 if the string was static.

Comment: im not able to call dbname, im can show the database on the gridview, but when i close form2 and launch it again the dbname was = null.